# using adaptive Cards 1.0,how to get actions in different columns?

Tags: c#, adaptive-cards

I have generated an adaptive card (AdaptiveCard 1.0 as 2.0 version is not supported by the emulator)using JSON format.

I want to have two buttons submit and cancel in two different columns. I am using C# to post this adaptive card.

I know we can use ActionSet but it is available in version 2.0 and if I use version 2.0 I am getting below error:

> [
>     {
>       "error": 12,
>       "message": "The specified card version (1.2) is not supported. The maximum supported card version is 1.1"
>     }
>   ]

Comment: There is no Adaptive Cards 2.0. I presume you mean 1.2 because that's in your error message and that's the version that action sets were introduced in. Emulator does support Adaptive Cards 1.2, so you may be able to get that working by updating Emulator. Since you're presumably not building a bot that will only be used on Emulator, what channel are you targeting? Web Chat is the only official client that currently supports Adaptive Cards 1.2.

Comment: I am targeting this Bot  for MS Teams

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Microsoft Teams does not support Adaptive Cards 1.2. You can see on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/resources/partners) which official clients support which versions of Adaptive Cards. However, if you just use the `actions` array normally in Adaptive Cards 1.0 then the actions will automatically appear side-by-side (in different "columns") in desktop and mobile Teams clients:

[image: Adaptive Card]

Please see the "Body & Actions" section of [my latest blog post](https://blog.botframework.com/2019/07/02/using-adaptive-cards-with-the-microsoft-bot-framework/) for more information.